# Select Point Programmatically (e.g. from TableView Cell or Button)

Tags: swift, highcharts

I am trying to figure out a way to programmatically highlight or select a data point on a HighCharts graph.

So far I have not figured out how to pull a HIPoint out of a series, much less select that point.  Also, if there is a way to get the tooltip hover to show up programmatically, rather than simply selecting the data point, that would be even better.

I have found many examples of how to do this in JavaScript, but the method of series[i].data[i].select() doesn't work in Swift, because data is [Any], and you can only set select on a HIPoint.

options.series[0].data[3].select() // doesn't work
(options.series[0].data[3] as! HIPoint).select() // crashes, because Any can't be converted into HIPoint

Data point on series[0] point[3] should be selected, or bring up the tooltip, but I can't figure out how to access the HIPoint to do anything with it at all.

Comment: Hi @D. Pratt, I do not know `swift` code, but generally you can set`selected` property for data point object. If you want to use some point method, you need to use a reference to a point through the chart. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5Lw1gc2u/

Comment: That's the issue with the Swift SDK; there doesn't seem to be a direct way to access the HIPoint (that I have found so far).  I can get to a series (which lives in chart.options.series, but series doesn't have a points array, which would allow me to set selected() on it.

Comment: Not a solution to the posted question, but an effective work around that I have found so far is to use HIAnnotations instead of trying to get points to select.  I can get coordinate values from the data, and post an annotation when selecting a tableview cell, which ends up doing pretty much what I want, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `HIPoint` class object to the data:

```
let options = HIOptions()

let chart = HIChart()
chart.type = "line"
options.chart = chart

let title = HITitle()
title.text = "Demo chart"
options.title = title

let line = HILine()

let point = HIPoint()
point.y = 71.5

line.data = [29.9, point, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

options.series = [line]
```

And refer to the point in this way:

```
let point = self.chartView.options.series[0].data[1] as! HIPoint
point.select()
```

Comment: Great, thank you!  Adding data as points was what I was missing!